# simplified css3 animation doesn't work

Tags: css, animation

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/h668zsnL/

I had simplified the blink class to this

```
-webkit-transition: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-transition: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-o-transition: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-ms-transition: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
transition: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
```

but it doesn't work? Where did I missed?

Comment: you need [`animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) -- `animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a `transition` insteed of an `animation`:

```
-webkit-animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-moz-animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-o-animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
-ms-animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
animation: blink 1s ease-in-out infinite;
```

Comment: So often I can't understand why people downvote a perfectly straight answer (ofc without a single comment). i DO admire how this web works, how it gets people involved making it great (for free) but still these so often downvotes should need some kind of moderation to check if not justified. Some people so often can't ditinct between a "not useful" answer from a "usefull" one. You may not like it but the answer may be usefull maybe not from the op but from future readers who use the search (as so many people should do before asking). In that case NO voting is the right way.